# Disable zoom on web-view react-native?

Tags: android, ios, webview, react-native, hybrid-mobile-app

How to disable zoom on `react-native` `web-view`,is there a property like `hasZoom={false}`(just an example) that can be included in the below `web-view` tag that can  disable zooming.
It has to be working on both android and ios.

```
<WebView
     ref={WEBVIEW_REF}
     source={{uri:Environment.LOGIN_URL}}
     ignoreSslError={true}
     onNavigationStateChange={this._onNavigationStateChange.bind(this)}
     onLoad={this.onLoad.bind(this)}
     onError={this.onError.bind(this)}
 ></WebView>
```

Comment: do you find any solution to avoid zoom on double click for iOS and Android in RN?

Comment: I think it's an issue reported on github .. https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/10536 check this out

Comment: This may help you. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50110920/how-to-zoom-out-in-webview-in-react-native/50127083#50127083

Answer (score 74, accepted):

Thought this might help others, I solved this by adding the following in the html `<head>` section:

`<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">`

Comment: how do you add such header? inside source ? can you please give an example?

Comment: @Smit - put in in the webpage's header.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. How can we insert this code into other webpage's header? are you suggesting below?
`<WebView source={{ uri: URL, html:'<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">' }} />`

sorry if I am doing it wrong but feel free to correct me.

Comment: Add the `meta` tag in your index.html (you can find it in your `reactproject/public` folder

Comment: This would only apply if you had control over the shown web page and thus doesn't answer the question.

Comment: Using meta tag above show blank screen, is there any solution yet?

Comment: This works, thank you great help @shahonseven

Answer (score 31):

**For those who want a clear idea**:

```
const INJECTEDJAVASCRIPT = `const meta = document.createElement('meta'); meta.setAttribute('content', 'width=device-width, initial-scale=0.5, maximum-scale=0.5, user-scalable=0'); meta.setAttribute('name', 'viewport'); document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(meta); `

 <WebView
  source={{ html: params.content.rendered }}
  scalesPageToFit={isAndroid() ? false : true}
  injectedJavaScript={INJECTEDJAVASCRIPT}
  scrollEnabled
 />
```

Comment: Had to remove 'width=device-width' in my case. You saved my time. Thanks.

Comment: yes, the values have to be changed according to your requirements.

Answer (score 14):

Try `scalesPageToFit={false}` more info in [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/webview.html)

Comment: Wow wow wow. This is a very clean option for maintaining screen size on mobile

Comment: This will only work on android, and will not on ios.

Answer (score 14):

If you are using `WKWebView` - `scalesPageToFit` prop does not work. You can check this [issue here](https://github.com/react-native-webview/react-native-webview/issues/483) that will lead you to [this one](https://github.com/react-native-webview/react-native-webview/issues/447#issuecomment-477201365)

Now to accomplish what you want you should use the `injectedJavascript` prop. But there is something else as described [here](https://github.com/react-native-webview/react-native-webview/blob/master/docs/Reference.md#injectedjavascript)

`Be sure to set an onMessage handler, even if it's a no-op, or the code will not be run.`

This took me some time to discover. So in the end you have something like this:

```js
const INJECTED_JAVASCRIPT = `(function() {
  const meta = document.createElement('meta'); meta.setAttribute('content', 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no'); meta.setAttribute('name', 'viewport'); document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(meta);
})();`;

<WebView
  source={{ uri }}
  scrollEnabled={false}
  injectedJavaScript={INJECTED_JAVASCRIPT}
  onMessage={() => {}}
/>
```

Comment: I've signed only to comment that this is the only solution that worked for me!

Comment: This works for both android and ios

Answer (score 10):

Little hacky stuff but it works

```
const INJECTEDJAVASCRIPT = 'const meta = document.createElement(\'meta\'); meta.setAttribute(\'content\', \'width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=0.99, user-scalable=0\'); meta.setAttribute(\'name\', \'viewport\'); document.getElementsByTagName(\'head\')[0].appendChild(meta); '



<WebView
        injectedJavaScript={INJECTEDJAVASCRIPT}
        scrollEnabled
        ref={(webView) => {
          this.webView = webView
        }}
        originWhitelist={['*']}
        source={{ uri: url }}
        onNavigationStateChange={(navState) => {
          this.setState({
            backButtonEnabled: navState.canGoBack,
          })
        }}
      />
```

**Note**
initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=0.99, user-scalable=0

Comment: hi, why is the maximum scale `0.99` instead of `1`?

Comment: Hi! Your solution is only working in android. Not in iOS. Do you have any idea about the iOS? How to disable pinch to zoom in iOS as well?

Answer (score 6):

I was also find me with this problem and I resolved using

setBuiltInZoomControls={false} like prop in WebView

example

```
<WebView
   /*all prop to use*/ 
   setBuiltInZoomControls={false}
/>
```

I hope that to be help

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This answer is what i want,thanks.My requirement is to disable pinch to zoom and  double tap to zoom on Android.Refer [here](https://github.com/react-native-webview/react-native-webview/blob/master/docs/Reference.md#setbuiltinzoomcontrols)

Answer (score 2):

I was able to disable zooming, text selection and other pointer events by wrapping `WebView` in a `View` and setting a few props:

```
<View pointerEvents="none">
  <WebView
    source={{ uri: webviewUrl }}
    scrollEnabled={false}
  />
</View>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for the reply. Well, it's still not giving the desired output.

`<View pointerEvents="none" style={{height: HEIGHT, width: 
           WIDTH}}>
               <WebView source={{ uri: URL }} scrollEnabled={false} />
         </View>`

Also I wasn't able to touch any buttons on webpage while using `pointerEvents="none"`
Check out the output here: https://files.slack.com/files-tmb/T02UA0972-FAG2SRTDW-b99f2fb411/screenshot_2018-05-01-19-15-14_1024.png

Desire output - https://files.slack.com/files-tmb/T02UA0972-FAFFBFFTJ-d0082bba5e/screenshot_2018-04-30-19-51-55_1024.png

Answer (score 0):

Just set `setBuiltInZoomControls={false}` should work in webview

Answer (score -2):

For anyone in the future, I solved this by adding the following css :

```
*:not(input) {
  user-select: none;
}
```

The above basically disable text selection on all elements, which during my testing disallowed zooming on webpage. FYI: I haven't dived deep into details, just stating its effects.