# How to Zoom out in WebView in react-native?

Tags: android, reactjs, webview, react-native

I am using "WebView" in react-native for rendering a web page. The web page doesn't have mobile-friendly UI.

When I open it in Chrome Browser, it looks like below. **AND I WANT TO RENDER IT LIKE BELOW**

[image]

But When I render below code, it looks like the image shown below.
Please see that I have tried different props `automaticallyAdjustContentInsets = {false}` , `scalesPageToFit={false}`. But it's not giving me the desire output.

```
render(){
    const URL  = "https://stellarterm.com";
    return(
          <WebView 
             source={{URL}}
          />
```

**Result**

[image]

**Please feel free to suggest any solution if you have. Any third party library will also be okay.**

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Your site has page width set in meta already `<meta name="viewport" content="width=1080">`

So you will need to override that with injectedJavaScript

`` injectedJavaScript={`const meta = document.createElement('meta'); meta.setAttribute('content', 'width=device-width, initial-scale=0.5, maximum-scale=0.5, user-scalable=0'); meta.setAttribute('name', 'viewport'); document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(meta); `}
scalesPageToFit={false} ``

Comment: Can you please explain more where should I add the above code.

Comment: @ZuhaKarim react-native `WebView` has a prop called `injectedJavaScript`. you add this code there

Answer (score 3):

The `user-scalable` property on the selected answer's injection must be set to 1 to enable manual screen scaling.

Answer (score 1):

I have used this line to Zoom and fit WebView content on every mobile screen

**scalesPageToFit={false}**

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had to change initial-scale=0.5 to initial-scale=1. I was rendering Google Forms in webview. Please see below code.

```
injectedJavaScript={`const meta = document.createElement('meta'); meta.setAttribute('content', 'width=100, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=0.5, user-scalable=0'); meta.setAttribute('name', 'viewport'); document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(meta); `}
```